# Modify dhtmlxGantt to work with multiple projects - Laravel5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, dhtmlx

I have integrated dhtmlxGantt in a Laravel5 project and everything is working as expected. But I want to modify it to store charts for more than one project. For that I want to add extra field called "project_id" and load data through a filter.

I have tried modifying the Controller with the following code :

```
$connector->render_links(                                  
    GanttLink::where('user_id', '=', 1)->get(),
    "id", 
    "source,target,type"                
);

$connector->render_table(                                  
    GanttTask::where('user_id', '=', 1)->get(),
    "id",                                                               
    "start_date,duration,text,progress,parent"                      
);
```

This solution allowed me to load the chart from the data base in the way I wanted. But It does not save the changes back to the database. I went through the dhtmlxGantt documentations but did not get any solution for this.

I found these links in my research and might be helpful.

[Link 1: Changing values before saving](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__data_management_howtos_updating.html#howcanichangevaluesbeforesaving)

[Link 2: Filtering results based on a parameter](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__filtration.html)

Please help me to modify my project in a way which allows to work (Load and Edit) on different charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Firstly, you need to add `project_id` column to the database table, then add the column to connector configuration:

```
$connector->render_table(new GanttTask(), "id", "start_date,duration,text,progress,parent,project_id");
```

Then you have to do some modifications to the client-side code. Use something like,

```
var project_id = "<?php echo $project['id']; ?>";
```

in order to take the variable into the `<script>..</script>`
Then modify your code by adding these two client-side handlers:

```
gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
                            if (task.project_id == project_id) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
```

and

```
gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskAdd", function (id, task) {
                            task.project_id = project_id;
                        });
```

First handler filters the results in the way you want before displaying the chart, and second handler attaches the `project_id` property before adding the task. Now you have a dhtmlxGatt which can display multiple projects.

Comment: how can I develop <script>...</script> file